# How can i properly bind the rotation property with two other properties?

Tags: java, javafx, properties, binding

I would like to draw an arrow in a JavaFX application, that rotates around an object that is bound to it (2 group objects that are connected with an arrow). To compute the correct angle I tried to compute it by substracting the two coordinates (end and start xy coordinates from the groups). But my arrow head will not move. Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

```
// controller code:
PlaceIcon startIconGroup = new PlaceIcon();
startIconGroup.setLayoutX(100);
startIconGroup.setLayoutY(120);
startIconGroup.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICKED, onClickEventHandler); // for dragging
startIconGroup.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DRAGGED, onDragEventHandler);
startIconGroup.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_PRESSED, onPressEventHandler);
workplace.getChildren().add(startIconGroup); // workplace is the pane were the nodes are shown

PlaceIcon endIconGroup = new PlaceIcon();
endIconGroup.setLayoutX(100);
endIconGroup.setLayoutY(120);
endIconGroup.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICKED, onClickEventHandler); 
endIconGroup.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DRAGGED, onDragEventHandler);
endIconGroup.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_PRESSED, onPressEventHandler);
endIconGroup.getChildren().add(startIconGroup);

RelationIcon relationIcon = new RelationIcon();
relationIcon.setStartNode(startNode);
relationIcon.setEndNode(endNode);

...

    EventHandler<MouseEvent> onDragEventHandler = new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
        /**
         * This method is used to compute the new position of an node. Therefore, the
         * position in pixels (x/yLayout) is incremented by coordinate change of mouse
         * movement.
         */
        @Override
        public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
            Group clickedElement = (Group) event.getSource();
//          Node node = clickedElement.getChildren().get(0);
            double offsetX = event.getSceneX() - mousePosition.get().getX();
            double offsetY = event.getSceneY() - mousePosition.get().getY();
            clickedElement.setLayoutX(clickedElement.getLayoutX() + offsetX);
            clickedElement.setLayoutY(clickedElement.getLayoutY() + offsetY);
            mousePosition.set(new Point2D(event.getSceneX(), event.getSceneY()));
            eventlog.setText("Move "+ clickedElement + " to x=" + clickedElement.getLayoutX() + " y="
                    + clickedElement.getLayoutY());
        }
    };
```

And here is the `PlaceIconClass`

```
public class RelationIcon extends Group {
    Line line;
    Polygon arrowHead;
    Group startNode;
    Group endNode;

    public RelationIcon() {
        //draw arrow line
        line = new Line();
        // draw arrow head  
        arrowHead = new Polygon();
        arrowHead.getPoints().addAll(new Double[]{
                -10.0, -20.0,
                10.0, -20.0,
                0.0, 0.0});
        // merge into a group
        this.getChildren().addAll(line, arrowHead);
    }

    public Group getStartNode() {
        return startNode;
    }

    public void setStartNode(Group startNode) {
        this.startNode = startNode;
        line.startXProperty().bind(this.startNode.layoutXProperty());
        line.startYProperty().bind(this.startNode.layoutYProperty());
    }

    public Group getEndNode() {
        return endNode;
    }

    public void setEndNode(Group endNode) {
        this.endNode = endNode;
        line.endXProperty().bind(this.endNode.layoutXProperty());
        line.endYProperty().bind(this.endNode.layoutYProperty());
        arrowHead.layoutXProperty().bind(this.endNode.layoutXProperty());
        arrowHead.layoutYProperty().bind(this.endNode.layoutYProperty());
        arrowHead.rotateProperty().bind(this.endNode.layoutXProperty());  // THIS WORKS
arrowHead.rotateProperty().bind(Bindings.createDoubleBinding(() -> { 
            double x = line.endXProperty().getValue() - line.startXProperty().getValue();
            double y = line.endYProperty().getValue() - line.startYProperty().getValue();
            System.out.println(x+" "+y);
            double a = Math.atan2(x, y);
            return Math.toDegrees(a);
        }));  // THIS WORKS NOT
    }
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: You haven't added any dependencies for the binding. You should add start and end coordinates of the line though: `return Math.toDegrees(a);
        }, line.endXProperty(), line.endYProperty(), line.startXProperty(), line.startYProperty()));` BTW: For all JavaFX properties in the core API getters exist, so you could replace e.g. `line.endXProperty().getValue()` by `line.getEndX()`.

Comment: Thank you so much! Now it works!